# Preview "duplicate" proposals in 10K tools on hover?

Tags: feature-request, review, 10k-tools, markdown-preview

I decided to take a crack at the 10K tools this morning and I see a bunch of duplicate flags. At the bottom, there's a yellow box that says "exact duplicate of {URL}". I have to click on the link to see the reference and then go back to the review queue in another tab.

Here's what it looks like now:

[image: Before]

I propose that a hover card be implemented, so that I can hover the link and see the question right there. It'll save time, and make the 10K tools that much more efficient. I'm thinking something like the profile cards that appear when you hover a users profile.

[image: After]

Comment: What review queue are you looking at? The close vote queue shows proposed duplicates in separate tabs *at the top*.

Comment: Added pictures.

Comment: That's the "Tools", aka 10K queue, not the "Review queue". Yes, that's more inconvenient. Click on the "Review" link at the top.

Comment: That is not the review queue. Use the review queue for dupe reviews instead. :-)

Comment: I only use the "Tools" for flagging "not-an-answer" answers :)